# How can I duplicate the category programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, adminhtml

Is there a way to duplicate a product on the admin side but not copy the category?

This would make it so much easier for us. I'm assuming it would be under Product.php but not to sure. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck on this? I also need to implement the same functionality.